# Exponentially well-approximable numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $\alpha \in [0,1]$ be irrational.  I'm interested in the decay rate of $\| n \alpha \|$ as $n \to \infty$, where $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the distance to the nearest integer.

For example:

- [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) says that every irrational $\alpha$ satisfies $\|n \alpha \| < n^{-1}$ infinitely often.
- The [Thue-Siegel-Roth theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem) says that no algebraic irrational $\alpha$ can satisfy $\|n \alpha \| < n^{-(1+\epsilon)}$ infinitely often.
- "$\alpha$ is Liouville" is equivalent to the statement that "for every $C>0$, $\| n \alpha \| < n^{-C}$ infinitely often".

My question: do there exist any $\alpha$ that satisfy $\|n \alpha \| < \exp(-cn)$ infinitely often, for some $c>0$?  If so, how big is the set of such $\alpha$? (for whatever sense of the word "big" you like)

Comment: Can't you just iterate the Liouville construction and consider say $\sum a_n$ where $a_n = 10^{-10^{n!}}$ or something like that?

Comment: There is the notion of an [ultra-Liouville number](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ultra-Liouville+number%22&filter=0), which is what might be called a [tetrated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) Liouville number (much stronger condition than your "exponential" Liouville number notion). Although much smaller than Hausdorff dimension zero (which the Liouville numbers are), they still form a large set from the Baire category sense (a co-meager set, hence among other things $c$-dense in every interval), which can be proved in essentially the same way as for Liouville numbers.

Comment: Of course such numbers exist, you can construct them defining a number whose continued fraction expansion has extremely large partial quotients. If $p_k/q_k$ is a continued fraction convergent, then $\|q_k \alpha\| \ll 1/(a_{k+1} q_k)$. 

The measure of numbers which have such infinitely many such extremely large partial quotients will be small, whatever measure you use. The Lebesgue measure is zero, the Hausdorff dimension is also zero. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vojt%C4%9Bch_Jarn%C3%ADk#Number_theory.